# Committing to a different branch with commit -r

Tags: version-control, cvs

Does CVS allow committing a file to a different branch than the one it was checked out from? The man page and [some sites](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/cvs-branches.html#checkin) suggest that we can do a `cvs ci -r branch-1 file.c` but it gives the following error:

> cvs commit: Up-to-date check failed for `file.c'
>   cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!

I did a `cvs diff -r branch-1 file.c` to make sure that contents of file.c in my `BASE` and `branch-1` are indeed the same.

I know that we can manually check out using `cvs co -r branch-1`, merge the main branch to it (and fix any merge issues) and then do a check in. The problem is that there are a number of branches and I would like to automate things using a script. [This thread](http://www.cvsnt.org/pipermail/cvsnt/2006-March/024257.html) seems to suggest that `-r` has been removed. Can someone confirm that?

If `ci -r` is not supported, I am thinking of doing something like:

- Make sure the branch versions and base version are the same with a `cvs diff`
- Check in to the current branch
- Keep a copy of the file in a temp file
- For each branch:

  - Check out from branch with `-r`
  - **replace the file with the temp file**
  - Check in (it'll go the branch as `-r` is sticky)
- Delete the temp file

The replacing part sounds like cheating to me - can you think of any potential issues that might occur? Anything I should be careful about? Is there any other way to automate this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a file may not be up-to-date even if `diff` shows zero output. For example, if you add a line of text to a file in one commit and remove it in the next you have zero difference along the path of **two revisions**.

As for the commit -r -issue. To me it seems like an experimental feature, and actually one you are better off by just using:

```
cvs update -r <branch> <file>
cvs update -j <ver> -j <ver> <file>
cvs commit <file>
```

Besides, propagating a single commit to all other branches programatically like the way you suggested is slightly questionable business since you usually need a quite a bit of human brain to resolve the conflicts.

Comment: If there was an edit-undo, the revision history would still reflect that even after I force commit. I just want to make sure that I don't commit to version whose contents differ from the contents of the base version that I am editing (and thus lose any changes made to that branch). And ya, human intervention seems to be the only practical way to fix the merge conflicts.